# Функция частота в массиве данных со скрытыми строками

Tags: excel

Имеется таблица с данными по дневным доходностям BTCUSD. Данный актив торгуется всю неделю - с понедельника по воскресенье. Требуется подсчитать разброс дневных доходностей конкретно по дням недели, например, только по воскресеньям:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подсчитать можно с помощью функции частота, которая в качестве первого аргумента принимает ссылку на массив данных. Однако в данном случае массив данных в таблице содержит скрытые строки с другими днями недели, доходность которых не должна быть учтена в подсчете. Как это реализовать? Простая ссылка на массив со скрытыми данными дает некорректный результат (на скрине выше частота была подсчитана по 99 строкам, хотя всего срок с воскресеньями 15).

Comment: Разброс - это найти `Max` и `Min` и определить процент отклонения? За 100% какую величину брать?

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA возможно я некорректно выразилась. Вот смотрите, у меня есть лист, содержащий массив данных в столбце returns (на скрине слева). Это дневные доходности, т.е. насколько процентов актив вырос за день, насколько упал. На втором листе (справа) содержатся карманы (от минус 25% и до 25% с шагом в 5%), напротив которого нужно указать, сколько дней имеет доходность в этом интервале. Т.е. функция частота подходит. Но проблема в том, что мне нужно выбирать из массива данных определенные дни, например, воскресенья, и посчитать частоту доходностей только этого дня недели

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Та же *ЧАСТОТА*, но сначала "отфильтровать" массив значений:

```
=ЧАСТОТА(ЕСЛИ('BTC-USD'!$G$2:$G$930="воскресенье";'BTC-USD'!$H$2:$H$930);A2:A12)
```

Формула массива, вводится в диапазон `B2:B12`: выделить диапазон, вписать формулу в строку формул, нажать `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками и размножиться в выделенном диапазоне.